# jQuery click body but not nav

Tags: jquery

```
$('body').on( "click", "body:not(nav)", function(e) {
```

The above doesn't fire at all. I'm trying to make it so that if I click any part of the body except the nav then it will do something

Comment: what is nav here? Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">NAV</div>
    <div id="other">Others</div>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$('html').on('click', function (e) {

    if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'nav') {
        // CLICKED SOME WHERE ELSE
    }


});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/65kbm/2/

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
 $('body').on('click', function(e) {

  if(e.target == '#navid') {
     e.stopPropagation();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    var thisnav = e.target;
    if (!$(thisnav).hasClass('site-nav')) {
        //the code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go recursively up - because you can click on children in nav I improved @sravis demo

```js
function goUp(element) {
 console.log(element);
  if(element.is("html") || element == undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  else if(element.is("nav")){
    return true;
  }
  else{
   return goUp(element.parent());
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').on('click', function (e) {
   console.log("--------------------");
      if (goUp($(e.target))) {
        console.log('you clicked on nav');
      } 
      else {
        console.log('clicked some where else');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
nav {
    background-color: #foo;
}
#other {
    background-color: #c81d87;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <nav>
      <div>
        <span>NAV</span>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="other">Others</div>
</body>
```

or

http://jsfiddle.net/65kbm/14/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'html', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('nav')) {
        return;
    }
    // do stuff
});
```

Alternatively add an html class *navigation* to your *<nav>* element.

```
$(document).on('click', 'html', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('navigation')) {
        return;
    }
    // do stuff
});
```